# How to connect Java spring application with Angular 4 application

Tags: spring, angular

I made a Spring rest application and Angular 4 application and I want to use Spring rest Api's in my Angular 4 application. Simple CRUD application. which could be the best format of communication between these application

Comment: can you look at this https://github.com/RobertRajcool/Angular2-Spring-Mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/). 
It is for AngularJS, but the server side code is absolutely the same in case of Angular 2,3,4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try not to club angular and spring-boot together, sure you can do this using webjars or similar libraries, but try not doing it. Spin off the angular app as a separate application (you can serve this Angular app either using nginx or nodeJs) and then route all the API calls through the Angular App to your Spring boot application. Now your spring boot application will be just a ( micro ) service which will have to deal only with the data, not the presentation (markup / style etc).